# JPA Spring Hibernate Rest API error Session is closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs

I am using Spring 4/Hibernate4 for a JAX-RS api. When I call get methode I run into ***org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed*** 
 **Note:** I already tried to annotate the service and dao methode with @Transactional but it doesn't work

My context looks like this

```
<bean id="ppEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence-demo.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ppRestPersistenceLegacy" />        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ppRestLegacyDS" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="fr.test.rest*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="ppRestLegacyDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ppRestLegacyDB" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />        
</bean>
```

On my DAO I have

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ppRestPersistenceLegacy")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<RcPosStatus> getRcPosStatus(String orderByInsertionDate) {

    String sqlString = null;
    if(orderByInsertionDate != null){
        sqlString = "SELECT s FROM RcPosStatus s" + " WHERE ROWNUM < 11 ORDER BY s.DATE_FROM " + orderByInsertionDate;
    } else {
        sqlString = "SELECT s FROM RcPosStatus s WHERE ROWNUM < 11";
    }        
    TypedQuery<RcPosStatus> query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlString, RcPosStatus.class);        
    return query.getResultList();

}
```

My service looks like this

```
    @Autowired
BufferDao bufferDao;


 // ******************** Read related methods implementation **********************     
public List<Buffer> getBuffers(String orderByInsertionDate, Integer numberDaysToLookBack) throws AppException {

    if(isOrderByInsertionDateParameterValid(orderByInsertionDate)){
        throw new AppException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), 400, "Please set either ASC or DESC for the orderByInsertionDate parameter", null , AppConstants.BLOG_POST_URL);
    }           
    List<Buffer> buffers = bufferDao.getBuffers(orderByInsertionDate);

    return buffers;
}
```

and finaly my resource

```
    @GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<RcPosStatus> getRcPosStatus(
        @QueryParam("orderByInsertionDate") String orderByInsertionDate,
        @QueryParam("numberDaysToLookBack") Integer numberDaysToLookBack)
        throws IOException, AppException {
            List<RcPosStatus> status = statusService.getRcPosStatus(
            orderByInsertionDate, numberDaysToLookBack);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding annotation bean to my application context

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />  
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="ppEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

And annotating the service methode with @Transactional

```
     // ******************** Read related methods implementation **********************     
@Transactional
public List<RcPosStatus> getRcPosStatus(String orderByInsertionDate, Integer numberDaysToLookBack) throws AppException {
```